# How do i change the active keying set by Python?

Tags: python, scripting

You can call the Change Keying Set menu by hotkey <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. But you cannot assign a hotkey to one of the single keying sets. It's always the whole menu. So I want to create a button in the tool shelf for the active keying set method LocRotScale to save me some clicks.

I would expect that a inserted button with `col.operator("anim.keying_set_active_set", text="LocRotScale").type = 'LocRotScale'` would set the keying set to LocRotScale. But it just calls the Change Keying Set menu. And throws me an error too.

> TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "LocRotScale" not found in ('DEFAULT')

How can i insert a button that sets the Keying set to LocRotScale directly with one click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `anim.keying_set_active_set` operator invokes a menu that lists the available keying sets. It does have a type property to bypass the menu, which allows you to specify the type value when calling it directly, but it doesn't seem to work when placing the operator in a panel or when setting keyboard shortcuts to use it - it looks like it is most likely due to the acceptable values being a dynamic list.

Changing the keying set is a simple task so it's easy to make a substitute yourself.

```
class SetKeyingSetOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Set the active keying set"""
    bl_idname = 'anim.set_keyingset'
    bl_label = 'Set the active keying set'

    type = bpy.props.StringProperty(default='LocRotScale')

    def execute(self, context):
        ks = context.scene.keying_sets_all
        ks.active = ks[self.type]
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Then you can use this operator to add a button in your panel.

```
row.operator('anim.set_keyingset', text='LocRot').type = 'LocRot'
```

This can all be put into an addon which can also setup some keyboard shortcuts to go with it. You can get [the addon here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/addonsByMe/master/change_keying_set.py), and adjust it to your liking.

As most keys are in use now, I used the key modifier setting. This isn't very popular yet, but it makes a normal key behave like <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> - in this configuration you hold down <kbd>K</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd> and it will set the keying set to `Location`. <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> for `Rotation` and <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> for `LocRotScale`

Comment: Works great. Many thanks. However, i cannot get it to work with WholeCharacter.

I have forced the enum to show with a wrong term. And there is indeed WholeCharacter missing.
This is what we have in the enum: ('__ACTIVE__', 'Location', 'Rotation', 'Scaling', 'BUILTIN_KSI_LocRot', 'BUILTIN_KSI_LocScale', 'LocRotScale', 'BUILTIN_KSI_RotScale', 'BUILTIN_KSI_VisualLoc', 'BUILTIN_KSI_VisualRot', 'BUILTIN_KSI_Vis). A few items are missing. For example Available, and of course WholeCharacter.
Any idea how i can get WholeCharacter to work too?

Comment: The list you show is the `bl_idname` of each keying set. The addon uses the `bl_label` which is the user visible name and can include spaces. I have updated the addon to include a comment that shows how to get a list of values. `[k.bl_label for k in bpy.context.scene.keying_sets_all]`

Comment: For `LocRot`, I had to set `ks.active = ks['Location & Rotation']` in the latest version 2.92.0

Answer (score 0):

You can modify 'Location' in the following to whatever you need:

```
for key in bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].keying_sets_all:
  if key.bl_label == 'Location':
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].keying_sets.active = key
```